# Mongo find next Tuesday

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the next Tuesday (day 2 of ISO Week) from today on. I have the current date from the global var `"$$NOW"` and the current day of ISO Week by the following operator: `{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }`. But I can't think of any way to get the date of the next Tuesday in MongoDB-Aggregation.

For example i have as Input:

```
"$$NOW" which is => new Date("2021-09-13T16:20:00Z") // Today Monday
```

And now I want to get the next Tuesday:

```
new Date("2021-09-14T16:20:00Z") // coming Tuesday
```

which is quite easy, but if there is a week shift, it gets a bit more difficult. If the NOW date would be:

```
"$$NOW" which is => new Date("2021-09-16T16:20:00Z") // coming Thursday would be Today
```

the next Tuesday would be the:

```
new Date("2021-09-21T16:20:00Z") // Tuesday next week
```

So I always want to get the next following Tuesday after Today.

At the end, I want to create a mongo pipeline like this:

```
[{
    $addFields: {
        "nextTuesday": new Date(" the date of the next Tuesday ")
    }
}]
```

I would be very happy about any help!

Comment: Would be nice if you add sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has the [$dayOfWeek](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/#-dayofweek--aggregation-) operator that returns 1 for Sunday, 7 for Saturday.

On that scale, the formula to find a desired day of the week would be:

```
(((desired_day + 6) - current_day) modulo 7) + 1
```

Which in the MongoDB aggregation language, would look like:

```
{$addFields:{
    nextTuesday:{
     $toDate:{
      $add:[
         "$$NOW",
         {$multiply:[
             86400000,
             {$add:[
                  1,
                  {$mod:[
                     {$subtract:[
                           9,
                           {$dayOfWeek:"$$NOW"}
                     ]},
                     7
                  ]}
             ]}
         ]}
      ]
     }
    }
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AobeC4Dswvk)